# Using socket API on IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets

for a little project I have to do the following task on my IPhone:

- open a TCP socket
- send a command to the server
- shutdown the WRITE part of the connection
- read the response from the server
- close the connection

I'm not experienced with socket programming - I've just started with network programming and I've already used the `CFStream` interface. But obviously streams are not adequate for this task.

Who can point me in the right direction? I tried to find a tutorial on Apples website about sockets, but there is nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at CoreFoundation's [CFSocket](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html). You can integrate it easily into your app's run loop, so there's no messing around with threads. This free [book excerpt](http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html) shows you how to use it.

CFSocket is a wrapper around a bsd socket, and lets you access the raw socket handle if ever you need to set special socket options (such as multicast).

If you're open to using 3rd-party libraries, [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) seems like a nice solution (never tried it myself).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an iPhone developer, but I was curious about your question so I had a look around.

I found this page: [Sockets on iPhone](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7774528#7774528)

Here's the code:

```
- (void)sendcmd:(NSString*)cmd {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *hostname= [defaults stringForKey:@"hostname"];

    NSHost *host=[NSHost hostWithName:hostname];

    if (host) {

        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        int sockfd;

        // Create a socket
        sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([[host address] UTF8String]);
        addr.sin_port = htons( 2001 );

        int conn = connect(sockfd, &addr, sizeof(addr)); 

        if (!conn) {

            NSData* data = [cmd dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

            ssize_t datasend = send(sockfd, [data bytes], [data length], 0);
            datasend++;

            //ssize_t   send(int, const void *, size_t, int) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(send);

            close(sockfd);

        } else {
            // create a popup here!

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[@"Connection failed to host " stringByAppendingString:hostname] message:@"Please check the hostname in the preferences." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }

    } else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[@"Could not look up host " stringByAppendingString:hostname] message:@"Please check the hostname in the preferences." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

A poster goes on to also suggest this library: [entropydb - SocketWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/entropydb/wiki/SocketWrapper)

Comment: Thanks for your support - SocketWrapper is on my level ;-) Yesterday a read a nice tutorial http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html and now may things are clear.